# How to combine radiogroup select with plain inputs in Django's forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to create a form in Django similar like you can find in Google calendar in the reminder's repeat section.
[image]

```
class ReminderFlatForm(ModelForm):
    WEEKS = (
        (1, 'M'),
        (2, 'T'),
        (3, 'W'),
        (4, 'T'),
        (5, 'F'),
        (6, 'S'),
        (7, 'S'),
        )
    REPEATS_BY = (
        (8, 'day of the month'),
        (9, 'day of the week')
        )
    ENDS = (
        (1, 'Never'),
        (2, 'After <input type="text" id="after_id"> occuriencies'),
        (3, '<input type="text" id="ondate_id">')
        )

    weeks = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=WEEKS,
        label="",
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        )
    months = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=REPEATS_BY,
        label="",
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
        )
    ends = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=ENDS,
        label="Ends",
        required=True,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect
        )
```

But instead of HTML elements, I have plain text. 
How can I do that with Django's forms?

Also, I'm using crispy forms if it's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) on the elements with html in them

```
   ENDS = (
        (1, 'Never'),
        (2, mark_safe('After <input type="text" id="after_id"> occuriencies')),
        (3, mark_safe('<input type="text" id="ondate_id">'))
        )
```

Comment: It is work but it is plaintext input, so how to combine with charfield?

Answer (score 0):

Besides, you could loop the fields in the template and paint them whatever you want. Kind of:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So, you would define your fields as a plain text (in your form), for then paint them in your template between you html elements.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/

Comment: I can just add pure HTML. But I need a reusable form.

Comment: Your form will be reusable. You are defining their fields, which will contains their values. The way you are deciding how to paint it must to made it in the template by the other hand.